# Java repaint() not working when called from a different class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My repaint works when called in the same class but not from another class. I haven't been able to find this issue elsewhere. I have put my code below. Thank you! The code is for making a calculator in a JFrame with 2 JPanels, one showing the user's input and one with all the buttons. I want to call repaint so the drawString() method changes as the user enters their input.

```
public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
    }

    public Calculator()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setSize(800,  800);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        Buttons b = new Buttons();
        Display d = new Display();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        frame.add(d);
        frame.add(b);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Buttons extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        private int z;
        public JButton[] buttons;
        public Display d;`enter code here`
        public String[] values;
        public String clickedButton;

        public Buttons()
        {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
            values = new String[100];
            for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = new String("");
            }
            addButtons();
        }

        public void addButtons()
        {
            Font courier = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 20);
            buttons = new JButton[20];

            for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
            {
                buttons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
                buttons[i].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                buttons[i].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                buttons[i].setFont(courier);
                buttons[i].setFocusable(false);
                buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
                buttons[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0, 100, 175, 255)));
                add(buttons[i]);
            }

            buttons[10].setVisible(false);
            buttons[10].setEnabled(false);
            buttons[11].setVisible(false);
            buttons[11].setEnabled(false);

            buttons[12].setText("C");
            buttons[13].setText("+");
            buttons[14].setText("-");
            buttons[15].setText("*");
            buttons[16].setText("/");

            buttons[17].setText("+/-");
            buttons[18].setText("^");
            buttons[19].setText("=");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String action = e.getActionCommand();
            d = new Display();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if(action.equals(Integer.toString(i)))
                {
                    values[d.i]+=Integer.toString(i);
                    System.out.println("should be repainting");
                    d.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Display extends JPanel
    {
        public Buttons b;
        public Font courier;
        public int i;

        public Display()
        {
            i = 0;
            b = new Buttons();
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            courier = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 50);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.setFont(courier);
            g.drawString(b.values[i], 50, 50);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be creating a new Display every time and telling that to repaint instead of the real one. Move your `Display d` variable into the Calculator class as a field, and don't declare new ones.

You create the original Display object as a local variable so it can't be accessed from elsewhere, so make this part use the class field instead:

```
Display d = new Display();
```

Also, this line in `actionPerformed` is creating a new instance and should be removed:

```
d = new Display();
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me another error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't call `repaint` from within a paint method.  This will cause the API to schedule anther paint request, which will eventually consume all your CPU cycles
2. You actually have two instances of `Display`, one which is on the screen, one which is not

While there are a few ways to fix this, one of the simpler would be to simply pass the instance of `Display` created to in `Calculator`s constructor to `Buttons`, for example...

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
    }

    public Calculator() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        Display d = new Display();
        Buttons b = new Buttons(d);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        frame.add(d);
        frame.add(b);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Buttons extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private int z;
        private JButton[] buttons;
        private String[] values;
        private String clickedButton;

        private Display d;

        public Buttons(Display d) {
            this.d = d;
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
            values = new String[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                values[i] = new String("");
            }
            addButtons();
        }
```

Then buttons can use that instance to display what ever it needs to display

```
        private int index = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String action = e.getActionCommand();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (action.equals(Integer.toString(i))) {
                    values[index] += Integer.toString(i);
                    d.setValue(values[index]);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Display extends JPanel {

        public Font courier;
        private String value;

        public Display() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            courier = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 50);
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
            repaint();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.setFont(courier);
            if (value != null) {
                g.drawString(value, 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any long-running loops in this that would block the event loop for a significant amount of time.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen The `actionPerformed` method will only paint the last loop's result - it's not about "long running" but blocking - if the instance of `d` was actually on the screen - see point 3

Comment: I don't think the loop will ever call `repaint` more than once. It could use a `break` for readability, but that's not the main issue.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen True, I see loops and repaint issues and immediately see blocked UI

Comment: thank you! I have changed that - I had meant to delete that before. I just had it to see if repaint inside the actual class was working. I also changed d (the instance of Display) to a field variable because it was making new instances each time. However, when I did that I got this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError as well as a bunch of other lines following it.

Comment: Have a look at my changes to Display - I removed the creation of Buttons

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you explain why you did this, how do the buttons cause a stack overflow error? Thank you.

Comment: @RohithVishwajith If buttons is creating an instance of display and display is creating an instance of buttons and buttons is creating an instance of display and ...